# The purpose of forall in RankNTypes

Tags: haskell

In writing some Haskell code with the help of `hlint`, I followed the prompt to add a type signature to a function. It injected something sort of like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

multipleOf :: forall a. Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
multipleOf divisor n = n `mod` divisor == 0
```

This language extension is new to me, but as I understand, this is identical with the simpler:

```
multipleOf :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
multipleOf divisor n = n `mod` divisor == 0
```

Every example of rank N types I've read about seem don't seem to add anything new over the polymorphism that was already available, and this `forall` syntax doesn't seem to add any value.

What am I missing? Is there a good example of what this `forall` syntax does beyond what's available without extensions?

Comment: Your particular example is not actually using a higher rank type. It's only using the `RankNTypes` extension to allow you to use explicit `forall` quantifiers in the type signature. There is another extension `ExplicitForAll` which allows you to use `forall` without turning on any new functionality.

Comment: @Ben, there's also the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, that actually makes these useful.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, I believe that's precisely why `ExplicitForAll` exists. Universal quantification (`forall`) has always existed as an *implicit* concept. So writing them explicitly is an "extension" that makes sense in its own right, independently of any other extension even though it doesn't enable you to **do** anything differently on its own. Since multiple type system extensions need explicit `forall`s, having a separate extension for just the `forall` syntax allows other extensions to depend on it, instead of depending on each other or duplicating the functionality.

Comment: @Ben, the problem is that the `forall`s mean different things depending on whether `ScopedTypeVariables` is on or not. It's best to start with `ScopedTypeVariables` and add things on top than to start with `ExplicitForAll` and risk breaking things when you realize you need to add `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: @dfeuer Do the `forall`s mean something different? I thought it was just the "implicitly foralled" variabels that could mean something different when you turn on `ScopedTypeVariables` (since they could be reinterpreted as references to an outer-scope variable, rather than introducing a new type variable).

Comment: @Ben, no, the implicitly quantified ones stay the same; explicitly quantified ones extend their scope. Pattern variable signatures become legal, and act as though explicitly quantified (most of the time).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing that you can limit the scope of the quantified type variable:

```
modifyPair :: (Num b, Num c) => (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> (b, c) -> (b, c)
modifyPair f (b, c) = (f b, f c)
```

Try writing that function without the `RankNTypes` extension. In particular, allowing the elements of the pair to be different types from each other.

This *specific* example isn't too useful, but the general idea holds. You can specify that an argument to a function must be polymorphic.

There's an additional trick you can perform with this tooling. The canonical example comes from `ST`. The goal of the `ST` library is to allow constrained use of mutable data.  That is, you can implement an algorithm involving true mutation, and present an external interface that's pure. `ST` itself takes care of proving that the use is safe via clever type system tricks:

```
newtype ST s a    = ... -- details aren't important
newtype STRef s a = ... -- details still aren't important

-- a standard-ish interface to mutable data
newSTRef :: ST s (STRef s a)
readSTRef :: STRef s a -> ST s a
writeSTRef :: STRef s a -> a -> ST s ()

-- the magic using RankNTypes
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

That extra type variable, `s`, is worth paying attention to.  It appears in both `ST` and `STRef`. Every function that manipulates an `STRef` makes sure that the `s` in the `ST` and `STRef` is the *same* type variable.  So when you get to `runST`, you find that the type `s` has to be unrelated to the type `a`. `s` has its scope more confined than that of `a`. The end result of this is that you can't write something like `runST newSTRef`. The type checker will reject it because the type variable `s` would have to escape the context in which it's quantified.

So there really are some handy tricks you can pull when you can specify that a function's argument must be polymorphic.